# How to connect a SPCO relay?

Tags: power, relay

I have a relay [SRM-1C-SL-5VDC](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/388244.pdf). I am trying to switch the load On/Off using this relay. I am not sure how to connect it correctly as there its not mentioned clearly in the datasheet. Which pin on the relay am I supposed to connect the Load? I have uploaded my schematic below. Pin 1 on the two pin connectors is the 'Live' rail and pin 2 is the 'Neutral' rail.

[image]

The footprint for the relay is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Note that you don't have a power supply on pin 4 of the relay.

Comment: @stevenvh - aye? but pin 4 is connected to the positive end of the diode. I will upload my footprint shortly, my PCB connections don't look right

Comment: But you don't have a voltage difference across the coil which causes a current. Pin 4 should be at 5 V so that the current goes from +5 V to GND via the coil and the transistor.

Comment: @stevenvh - thanks steven. I have corrected the schematic, forgot the 5V supply lol. You reckon the footprint I have uploaded goes with the schematic component of the Relay?

Comment: The pin assignments aren't correct, you should swap 2 and 4. I added pin numbers to the drawing in my answer. (the coil connections may be mutually swapped.)

Comment: @stevenvh - awesome I needed to confirm that. thanks steven great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "Live" (the phase) enters at P1-1 and leaves switched at P2-1. So from there you go to the load, whose other side you connect to the neutral. It doesn't seem that the neutral connects on both connectors serve any purpose, except perhaps that they avoid that you have them just lying around. So that could be a safety measure.

**edit**

[image]

The numbers agree with the numbering in your schematic, so don't be misled by the pin arrangement on the relay: the three pins on the left are not the contacts! The diagram shows the connections, with the contacts for the relay unpowered, so the bottom contact is NC (normally closed), the top one NO (normally open).

The dashed outline *suggests* that this is bottom view, but you can make sure by using your multimeter and measure the resistance between the center left pin and the ones on the right. The one which measures zero ohm is the normally closed contact, you want the other one and the center left.

Comment: thanks steve but what I really want to know is how to connect this particular relay. since the relay is SPCO contact configuration, I'm not sure how to connect the relay correctly.

Comment: @David - edited. Hope it's more clear now. If not you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: thanks steven, I should have made the question more clear. Anyway, looking at the pins on the left, the two pins (top and the bottom) are the coil pins right? and the one in the middle is Common? So, referring back to my schematic the top and the bottom pins are pins labelled 4 and 5 right? And pin labelled 1 is common?

Comment: @David - completely correct.